# What is the most efficient way of selecting data from relational database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just started working with databases and 
I have this data sample from PostgreSQL tutorial
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

Which diagram looks like this:
[image]

I want to find all film categories rented in for example Canada. Is there a way of doing it without using SELECT within SELECT.. statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_id IN (
    SELECT category_id FROM film_category WHERE film_id IN (
        SELECT film_id FROM film WHERE film_id IN (
            SELECT film_id FROM inventory WHERE inventory_id IN (
                SELECT inventory_id FROM rental WHERE staff_id IN (
                    SELECT staff_id FROM staff WHERE store_id IN (
                        SELECT store_id FROM store WHERE address_id IN (
                            SELECT address_id FROM address WHERE city_id IN (
                                SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE country_id IN (
                                    SELECT country_id FROM country WHERE country IN ('Canada')
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I'm sure there must be something that i'm missing.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  and `JOIN` again.

Comment: Even with joins that query is gonna be expensive. And, PostgreSQL does not automatcvally create indexes to search children rows for foreign keys: you'll need to create them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is to use [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) instead of all these nested subqueries:

```
select distinct c.category_id, c.name 
from category c
inner join film_category fc on fc.category_id = c.category_id
inner join inventory i on i.film_id = fc.film_id
inner join rental r on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
inner join staff s on s.staff_id = r.staff_id
inner join store sr on sr.store_id = s.store_id
inner join address a on a.address_id = sr.address_id
inner join city ct on ct.city_id = a.city_id
inner join country cr on cr.country_id = ct.country_id
where cr.country = 'Canada'
```

For your requirement you must join 9 tables (1 less than your code because the table `film` is not really needed as the column `film_id` can link the tables `film_category` and `inventory` directly).
Notice the aliases for each table which shortens the code and makes it more readable and the `ON` clauses which are used to link each pair of tables.
Also the keyword `DISTINCT` is used so you don't get duplicates in the results because all these joins will return many rows for each category.